# В чем проблема?,помогите ее решить, пожалуйста

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вроде все правильно,но программа не работает перед запуском

Comment: Копируем код - вставляем в вопрос. За картинку вместо кода тут раздают минусы, а не ответы.

Comment: У вас "возникли ошибки сборки"... Обычно они выводятся в окошке сборки.

Answer (score 4):

Предкомпилированный заголовок `stdafx.h` всегда должен подключаться первым.

Поменяйте строки:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
```

на:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
```